# how to call a function in php using string

Tags: php, string, function

```
class AC{
    public $name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name; 
    }
}

$string = 'abc=new AC("Example");';
```

$string contains a string which is used to call class AC.
I want to execute this function and call `getName()` function of AC class.

Comment: You really need to rethink this, but if you INSIST on doing it, http://php.net/eval, and may Alan Turing have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Shall I create new class pass this variables to them and execute them; @MarcB

Comment: What is the desired goal after this aproach?

Comment: @DarkBee Above string is showing only function calling once but in reality it calls function more than 100 times.
dont worry ,i have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$className = "AC";
$obj = new $className($params); // Pass params as array for example, if you want maximal dynamic (or make the number of arguments dynamic)
```

And for functions:

```
$func = "getName";
$obj->$func($params);
```

Comment: $obj should also a string

Comment: @user1675595: Then you make `$$str->$func($params);`